# Зацикливание функции PyTelegramBotAPI python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, декоратор

Пишу телеграмм-бота на python. Для обработки сообщений, использую декоратор @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True). Вообще, функции рабочие, при вводе первой команды всё функционирует, но когда ввожу другую команду, функция которой тоже использует данный декоратор, происходит зацикливание - программа опять пытается обрабатывать данные по первой команде. Прикрепляю весь код, чтобы проще была понятна проблема

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):

    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('sticker.webp', 'rb'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, {0.first_name}!".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот, который поможет вам с математикой".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы можете:")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Написать команду /discr, чтобы посчитать дискриминант и значения x")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Написать команду /figures, чтобы узнать формулу площади нужной фигуры") # Присылает картинками
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Написать команду /stepen, чтобы возвести нужное число в любую степень")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Написать команду /prime, чтобы узнать, простое число или составное")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Написать команду /gcd, чтобы найти наибольший общий делитель двух чисел")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Написать команду /random, чтобы сгенерировать случайное число в нужном вам диапазоне")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['gcd'])

def gcd(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите два числа через пробел')

    def numbers(a, b):
        while int(a) != int(b):
            if int(a) > int(b):
                a = int(a) - int(b)
            else:
                b = int(b) - int(a)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Наибольший общий делитель: ' + str(a))

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def check_text(message):
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            a = int(line.split(' ')[0])  # разбиваем строку на элементы, которые написаны через пробел и сразу преобразовываем в тип данных int
            b = int(line.split(' ')[1])
            numbers(a, b)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 2 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['prime'])

def prime(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число, которое будем проверять')

    def is_prime(number):
        result = str(number) + ' - Простое число'
        i = 2
        while i < number:
            if number % i == 0:
                result = str(number) + ' - Составное число'
            i += 1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def check_text(message):
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            number = int(line)
            is_prime(number)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только число')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['stepen'])

def stepen(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите 2 числа через пробел:\nПервое - число, которое будем возводить в степень\nВторое - степень, в которую будем возводить в число')

    def nums(a, b) -> int:
        result = a ** b
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Результат: ' + str(result))

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def check_text(message):
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            a = int(line.split(' ')[0])  # разбиваем строку на элементы, которые написаны через пробел и сразу преобразовываем в тип данных int
            b = int(line.split(' ')[1])
            nums(a, b)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 2 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['figures'])

def figure(message):

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Треугольник", callback_data='triangle')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Трапеция", callback_data='trapeze')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Параллелограмм", callback_data='parallelogramm')
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ромб", callback_data='rombo')
    item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Квадрат", callback_data='square')
    item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Прямоугольник", callback_data='rectangle')
    item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Круг", callback_data='circle')
    item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Эллипс", callback_data='ellipse')
    item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Многоугольник", callback_data='multitangle')
    item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сектор круга", callback_data='sector_circle')
    item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сегмент круга", callback_data='segment_circle')

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите фигуру, формулу(ы) площади которой мне прислать', reply_markup=markup)
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

    def callback_inline(call):

        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'triangle':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\triangle1.png', 'rb'))
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\triangle2.png', 'rb'))
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\triangle3.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'trapeze':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\trapeze1.png', 'rb'))
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\trapeze2.png', 'rb'))
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\trapeze3.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'parallelogramm':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\parallelogramm.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'rombo':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\rombo.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'square':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\square.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'rectangle':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\rectangle.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'circle':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\circle.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'ellipse':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\ellipse.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'multitangle':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\multitangle.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'sector_circle':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\sector_circle.png', 'rb'))
            elif call.data == 'segment_circle':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\segment_circle.png', 'rb'))

        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Здесь вы выбирали фигуру...', reply_markup=None)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['discr'])

def discriminant(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите 3 аргумента (a, b, c) через пробел')

    def discr(a, b, c) -> int:
        discr: float
        discr = int(b) ** 2 - (4 * int(a) * int(c))
        if discr < 0:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Дискриминант отрицательный, корней нет')
        else:
            discr **= 0.5
            x1 = (int(-b) + discr) / (2 * int(a))
            x2 = (int(-b) - discr) / (2 * int(a))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Дискриминант: " + str(discr ** 2))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Корень из дискриминанта: " + str(discr))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Результат 1: " + str(x1))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Результат 2: " + str(x2))

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)

    def check_text(message):
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            a = int(line.split(' ')[0])  # разбиваем строку на элементы, которые написаны через пробел и сразу преобразовываем в тип данных int
            b = int(line.split(' ')[1])
            c = int(line.split(' ')[2])
            discr(a, b, c)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 3 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Прикладываю фотографию с неправильной работой:
[image: Фото]
Команда /gcd сработала верно. Затем вбиваю команду /prime, которая должна принять одно число, написать в ответ, простое число или составное. Но работает неверно, т.к. ждёт ОПЯТЬ два числа, как в команде /gcd.

Я читал документацию, понимаю, что срабатывает первый попавшийся декоратор, но как мне решить проблему? Решение не могу найти уже 3 дня.

Comment: Сделайте что то-типо базы в которой будете записывать состояние. И проверяйте состояние каждый раз когда приходит новое сообщение от пользователя.

Comment: Можно-ли по конкретнее пожалуйста? Как это реализовать?

Comment: Я подключал базу sql и записывал туда chat id и добавлял нужный столбцы для сохранение информации. и добавлял состояние пользователя и менял когда нужно. В вашем случае когда приходит команда.

Comment: Как это поможет избавиться от зацикливания в результате последовательного поиска декоратора в данной библотеке?

Comment: Я бы написал отдельный декоратор для обработки обычного текста. При каждом новом сообщении проверял состояние, и отправлял сообщение в нужный декоратор, а там проверял если это не команда то обрабатываем и выводим результат.

Comment: Если не трудно, можете написать, пожалуйста? Просто с ботами не так давно работаю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106198/discussion-between-mihailpy-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий код только вам нужно будет создать базу данных.
В базе должно быть так.

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "user_id"   INTEGER,
    "user_name" TEXT,
    "status"    TEXT
);
```

Код вот. Я еще добавил команду help.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3 as lite
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

data_users = 'data.db'


def new_users(user_id, username):  
    con = lite.connect(data_users)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select user_id from users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))

    if not (user_id,) in cur.fetchall():
        con = lite.connect(data_users)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
            (user_id, username, ""))
        con.commit()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
#     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('sticker.webp', 'rb'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, {0.first_name}!".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот, который поможет вам с математикой".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы можете:\nНаписать команду /discr, чтобы посчитать дискриминант и значения x\nНаписать команду /figures, чтобы узнать формулу площади нужной фигуры\nНаписать команду /stepen, чтобы возвести нужное число в любую степень\nНаписать команду /prime, чтобы узнать, простое число или составное\nНаписать команду /gcd, чтобы найти наибольший общий делитель двух чисел\nНаписать команду /random, чтобы сгенерировать случайное число в нужном вам диапазоне")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])

def help(message):
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
#     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('sticker.webp', 'rb'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы можете:\nНаписать команду /discr, чтобы посчитать дискриминант и значения x\nНаписать команду /figures, чтобы узнать формулу площади нужной фигуры\nНаписать команду /stepen, чтобы возвести нужное число в любую степень\nНаписать команду /prime, чтобы узнать, простое число или составное\nНаписать команду /gcd, чтобы найти наибольший общий делитель двух чисел\nНаписать команду /random, чтобы сгенерировать случайное число в нужном вам диапазоне")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['stepen'])

def stepen(message):
    def nums(a, b) -> int:
        result = a ** b
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Результат: ' + str(result))

    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    if message.text == '/stepen':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите 2 числа через пробел:\nПервое - число, которое будем возводить в степень\nВторое - степень, в которую будем возводить в число')
        con = lite.connect(data_users)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?", ("stepen", user_id,))
        con.commit()

    else:
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            a = int(line.split(' ')[0])  # разбиваем строку на элементы, которые написаны через пробел и сразу преобразовываем в тип данных int
            b = int(line.split(' ')[1])
            nums(a, b)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 2 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['discr'])

def discriminant(message):
    def discr(a, b, c) -> int:
        discr: float
        discr = int(b) ** 2 - (4 * int(a) * int(c))
        if discr < 0:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Дискриминант отрицательный, корней нет')
        else:
            discr **= 0.5
            x1 = (int(-b) + discr) / (2 * int(a))
            x2 = (int(-b) - discr) / (2 * int(a))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Дискриминант: " + str(discr ** 2))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Корень из дискриминанта: " + str(discr))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Результат 1: " + str(x1))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Результат 2: " + str(x2))

    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    if message.text == '/discr':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите 3 аргумента (a, b, c) через пробел')
        con = lite.connect(data_users)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?", ("discriminant", user_id,))
        con.commit()

    else:
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            a = int(line.split(' ')[0])  # разбиваем строку на элементы, которые написаны через пробел и сразу преобразовываем в тип данных int
            b = int(line.split(' ')[1])
            c = int(line.split(' ')[2])
            discr(a, b, c)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 3 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['prime'])

def prime(message):
    def is_prime(number):
        result = str(number) + ' - Простое число'
        i = 2
        while i < number:
            if number % i == 0:
                result = str(number) + ' - Составное число'
            i += 1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)

    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    if message.text == '/prime':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число, которое будем проверять')
        con = lite.connect(data_users)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?", ("prime", user_id,))
        con.commit()

    else:
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            number = int(line)
            is_prime(number)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только число')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['gcd'])

def gcd(message):
    def numbers(a, b):
        while int(a) != int(b):
            if int(a) > int(b):
                a = int(a) - int(b)
            else:
                b = int(b) - int(a)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Наибольший общий делитель: ' + str(a))

    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    if message.text == '/gcd':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите два числа через пробел')
        con = lite.connect(data_users)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?", ("gcd", user_id,))
        con.commit()

    else:
        line = message.text  # получаем строку, которую написал пользователь
        try:
            a = int(line.split(' ')[0])  # разбиваем строку на элементы, которые написаны через пробел и сразу преобразовываем в тип данных int
            b = int(line.split(' ')[1])
            numbers(a, b)  # вызываем функцию, которая обрабатывает аргументы нужным для Вас методом
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 2 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['figures'])

def figure(message):
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Треугольник", callback_data='triangle')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Трапеция", callback_data='trapeze')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Параллелограмм", callback_data='parallelogramm')
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ромб", callback_data='rombo')
    item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Квадрат", callback_data='square')
    item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Прямоугольник", callback_data='rectangle')
    item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Круг", callback_data='circle')
    item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Эллипс", callback_data='ellipse')
    item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Многоугольник", callback_data='multitangle')
    item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сектор круга", callback_data='sector_circle')
    item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сегмент круга", callback_data='segment_circle')

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите фигуру, формулу(ы) площади которой мне прислать', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'triangle':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\triangle1.png', 'rb'))
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\triangle2.png', 'rb'))
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\triangle3.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'trapeze':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\trapeze1.png', 'rb'))
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\trapeze2.png', 'rb'))
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\trapeze3.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'parallelogramm':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\parallelogramm.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'rombo':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\rombo.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'square':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\square.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'rectangle':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\rectangle.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'circle':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\circle.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'ellipse':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\ellipse.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'multitangle':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\multitangle.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'sector_circle':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\sector_circle.png', 'rb'))
        elif call.data == 'segment_circle':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('figures\\segment_circle.png', 'rb'))

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Здесь вы выбирали фигуру...', reply_markup=None)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    con = lite.connect(data_users)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select status from users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)
    if results[0][0] == "discriminant":
        discriminant(message)
    elif results[0][0] == "gcd":
        gcd(message)
    elif results[0][0] == "prime":
        prime(message)
    elif results[0][0] == "stepen":
        stepen(message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Короче говоря когда приходит команда выполняются функция и состояние записывается в базу. А когда приходит простое сообщение, то проверяется состояние и вызывается функция с обработкой сообщения.

Comment: Всё сделал как у вас, но есть ошибки.

Comment: Какие? Bot не работает?

Comment: Я могу скринами прислать. Может, в телеграмм?

Comment: File "bot2.py", line 88, in discriminant
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
  File "bot2.py", line 14, in new_users
    cur.execute("select user_id from users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database

Comment: Вы файл  базы создали?

Comment: Хотите я у себя запущу

Comment: Да, я создал. Сюда можно фото прислать?

Comment: Давайте через какую-нибудь соц сеть я вам пришлю папу со всем проектом

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['gcd'])
def gcd(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите два числа через пробел')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, numbers)


def numbers(message):
    print(message.text.split()[0], message.text.split()[1])
    if int(message.text.split()[0]) > int(message.text.split()[1]):
        a = int(message.text.split()[0]) - int(message.text.split()[1])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Наибольший общий делитель: ' + str(a))
    else:
        a = int(message.text.split()[1]) - int(message.text.split()[0])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Наибольший общий делитель: ' + str(a))



@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def check_text(message):
    try:
        numbers(message)
    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ввести нужно только 2 числа ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неправильно работает ваш пример. на 2 2 должен выдавать 2. На 3 8 должен выдавать 1

Comment: согласно вашего кода: int(a) - int(b) или int(b) - int(a). пусть a = 2, b = 2, тогда 2 - 2 = 0 и 2 - 2 = 0.

я взял за основу ваш код

Comment: Нет, согласно моему коду, цикл выполняется до тех пор, пока a != b. Сами функции работают верно. Я сразу на этом акцентировал внимание. Мне нужно изменить что-то с декораторами, чтобы выставить верный приоритет выполнения