# python telebot переход между функциями

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем доброго!
Внутри бота пытаюсь перейти между функциями ping и pos через запись в БД как рекомедовалось [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1103971/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-pytelegrambotapi-python?rq=1). Но перехода в функцию /pos не происходит. Мне нужно чтобы пользователь вводил /ping и действовал внутри этой функции, когда ввел /pos действовал внутри нее, пока не запросит другую команду.
Попробовал внутри /ping разместить ссылку на /pos
`if message.text == '/pos: posinfo_db(message)'` Переход в /pos происходит (и запись в БД тоже) но снова возвращает в /ping

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, subprocess
import telebot
import sqlite3 as lite

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
data_users = 'data.db'

#запись в БД состояний пользователя, для перехода между функциями
def new_users(user_id, username):  
    con = lite.connect(data_users)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select user_id from users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))

    if not (user_id,) in cur.fetchall():
        con = lite.connect(data_users)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (user_id, username, ""))
        con.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['ping'])
def start_message(message):
    # print(message)
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введи IP для пинга')
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id   
    host = message.text.lower()        
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 3', '-i 0,5', 'host'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, proc)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не удалось выполнить запрос, возможно вы написали не корретный или IP')

#нужно оставаться в этой функции пока пользователь не введет другую, например /ping
@bot.message_handler(commands=['pos'])
def posinfo_db(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Тут можно получить инфо о кассах')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def posinfo(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(user_id, message.from_user.first_name)
    con = lite.connect(data_users)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?", ("pos", user_id,))
    con.commit()
    if message.text == '/pos':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введи SHOP для получения списка касс')
        host = message.text.lower()        
        if len(host) == 4:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Получить список касс') 
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Получить информацию с касс')         

#вставил обработчик сообщений но помоему он не работает
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
    con = lite.connect(data_users)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select status from users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)
    if results[0][0] == "ping":
        get_text_messages(message)
    elif results[0][0] == "pos":
        posinfo(message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе разобрался, мешал дополнительный декоратор в первой функции. В итоге оставил так

```
def get_text_messages(message):
    host = message.text.lower()
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    new_users(user_id, message.from_user.first_name)
    update_user_status('ping', user_id)  
    if message.text == '/ping': 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите IP')            
    elif message.text != '/ping':        
        try:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 3', '-i 0,5', f'{host}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, proc)
        except:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не удалось выполнить запрос, возможно вы написали не корретный или IP')
```